# Is there a way to compile solidity code to javascript in javascript?

Tags: solc

This example constructs the javascript code from a solidity code in a shell script.

https://github.com/okue/Hello-Ethereum/blob/master/bin/compile

Is there a function in javascript that can convert a solidity code to a javascript code without having to rely an external command `solc`?

Answer (score 1):

`solc` is the Solidity compiler, is not a command that convert the solidity code in javascript. The compiler generate an output that contains the ABI, bytecode, metadata and other info as [described here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/using-the-compiler.html#output-description).

Once the code is compiled its bytecode will be deployed into the blockchain and its abi will be used as interface. The script you linked is doing this: it compiles the solidity code with `solc` and deploy it with `web3`, printing its address at the end.

You can see the same code [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract) in javascript that does the same.